# BizTalk Tracking profile

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-bam

I'm experiencing an issue with my tracking profile that spans multiple applications. after a deployment of one of the exoncerned applications, my tracking profile stops intercepting the data defined within.
is somene has already experienced this issue?

Comment: What is "exoncerned"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If one of the ports in your BAM tracking profile does not exist any more (or has been renamed), it stops working for everything.  You need try to reapply the tracking profile and it will tell you which ports are the issue. Then you save it as a file, edit those out or amend them, and reapply the profile

Comment: this not the case for me, when I reapply the traking profile it's applied successfully. no warnings about any missing artifacts.